# Calculating the Number of Two Pair Hands in Poker

Tags: combinatorics

My gut instinct is computing the number of possible poker hands with two pairs was to say there are 52 card for the first card, then 3 that match that one, then 48 remaining, the 3 to match that one, then 44 remaining, so 52*3*48*3*44, which is wrong. Why is it wrong? There are repeats, but I think this method is just wrong in general. I know the correct method, I just don't know why this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With $52\times 3$, you are already counting AH-AS and counting separately AS-AH.

Similarly, when you multiply by $48\times 3$, you are counting a pair of aces and a pair of kings, and then again re-counting a pair of kings and a pair of aces.

However, this technique is not hopeless; you need to divide by 2 (for double-counting the first pair), by 2 again (for double-counting the second pair), and by 2 yet again (for reversing the two pairs).  Hence, divide this by 8 and you should get the right answer.